# Problems with PDFRenderer

Tags: java, pdf, printing, dialog, pdfrenderer

Do you have any ideas how to print PDF file using standard Java libraries with showing dialog window?

```
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
            try {pjob.print();}
            catch (PrinterException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
             }
         }
```

I had problems with finding a solution. Was trying to use PDFRenderer, but, i dont know how, it prints my .pdf just on the 1/4 surface of a page... I would be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

To use the pdfRenderer library I basically follow the step from this guy:

http://lynema.org/2010/12/29/printing-a-pdf-in-java-with-pdfrenderer

As far as why when you print your image is off-scaled it's because of how PDFPrintPage was implemented. The link I showed you above show how to go around the problem. As for the source code for PDFPrintPage the link below has it:

http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2008/01/17/print-a-pdf-document-in-java/

I try to understand the logic in PDFPrintPage and I manipulate my image size and the paper size to fit and now I'm printing PDF successfully using PDFRenderer

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could include a description in your answer.

Comment: While content of linked article may answer OP question you need to assume that links can become invalid in the future. For that reason you should always post relevant parts from links and leave them as reference for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF is not A4, you will need to configure some transformations to scale it.

JPS has lots of options to control printing.

Comment: The problem is that PDF is A4. I've tried to use other libraries, but couldnt find satisfying solution. Do You have any ideas how to send a PDF file to PrinterJob object?

Comment: If you cannot use JPS, you can always use native printing. I wrote an article on ways to Print PDF files in Java at http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/